# Is there a way to "click" on a link extracted from html text using C#?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have the text body of an email in html, and that email has a link to another webpage in it (so the url is in html). I would like to know if there's a way in C# to "click" on this link and then extract the html information from the page I would be redirected to if I clicked on the link normally.

Comment: You should extract the link and make a connection to that URL yourself. Make some code and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the System.Net.WebClient to download the html from the url.

```
 var html = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```